# php syntax error if condition

Tags: php, url, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to include this if condition inside my code :

`if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'demo'){
    // Do something
}`

I want to trigger a part of my code only when this condition is true, so my entire code is looking like this :

```
<?php

abstract class ECF_Field_Type {
    private static $types = array();
    protected $name;

    /* Constructor */
    public function __construct() {
        self::register_type( $this->name, $this );
    }

    /* Add a type to the types list */
    private static function register_type( $name, $type ) {
        self::$types[$name] = $type;
    }

    /* Return the appropriate type */
    public static function get_type( $name ) {
        return array_key_exists( $name, self::$types )
            ? self::$types[$name] : self::get_default_type();
    }

    /* Return all types */
    public static function get_types() {
        return self::$types;
    }

    /* Get default type */
    public static function get_default_type() {
        return self::get_type( 'text' );
    }

    /* Display form field */
    public abstract function form_field( $name, $field );

    if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) == 'demo'){

        public function display_field( $id, $name, $value ) {
            return "<span class='ecf-field ecf-field-$id'>"
                . "<strong class='ecf-question'>$name:</strong>"
                . " <span class='ecf-answer'>$value</span></span>\n";
        }

    }

    /* Display field plain text suitable for email display */
    public function display_plaintext_field( $name, $value ) {
        return "$name: $value";
    }

    /* Get the description */
    abstract public function get_description();
}
?>
```

When I'm checking this in my browser I get 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting T_FUNCTION in` `if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'demo'){`

If I put this `if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'demo'){ // Do something }` outside the `abstract class ECF_Field_Type {` the condition is working fine.

How can I get that `if`condition to work inside that `abstract class` ?

I just want to be able to run that `public function display_field( $id, $name, $value )` when that condition is true.

Comment: You should allways avoid dynamic code in your application. no matter if it's a function or a class. It will result into loads of problems!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have code "outside" of a method in a class. e.g.

```
class foo {
   if (true) { ... };   <---bad code
   function bar() {
      if (true) { ... } <-- ok code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public function display_field( $id, $name, $value ) {
if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'demo'){
    return "<span class='ecf-field ecf-field-$id'>"
        . "<strong class='ecf-question'>$name:</strong>"
        . " <span class='ecf-answer'>$value</span></span>\n";
  }
else 
return "";
}
```